# list of PostgreSQL trusted languages?

Tags: postgresql, security, functions, postgresql-extensions

I am trying to find a list of PostgreSQL **trusted** procedural languages (PL) as I often need to use a PL in a non-superuser environment.

But I couldn't find a definitive answer. For example, the [Postgres documentation here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plperl-trusted.html) suggest that there is a both a trusted and an untrusted PL for perl, a language that I am not very familiar with. [Here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createlanguage.html), it says the `TRUSTED` keyword is something you can specify when creating a PL language, which may be ignored under circumstances.

But I also have the (possibly wrong) impression that certain PL languages are trusted only (e.g. JavaScript PL/V8) or untruested only (Python). [Other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848704/postgresql-running-python-stored-procedures-as-a-normal-user) seem to suggest that one can tweak pg to make even `python` a trusted language with something like:

```
UPDATE pg_language SET lanpltrusted = true WHERE lanname = 'plpythonu';
```

My question is more practical than theoretical. Basically:

Is it generally true that any PL can be both set up to be trusted and untrusted?

If not, what are the **specific** languages that can be set up to be trusted or are trusted.

(*By "trusted", I mean normal users should have effectively the same rights when creating/executing/modifying functions in the PL language*. Also, I am using Postgres 9.x)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is it generally true that any PL can be both set up to be trusted and untrusted?

No. Any PL can be *marked* as trusted or untrusted, but if you park a PL that doesn't support running trusted as trusted, it'll either notice that and `ERROR` or it'll silently run without sandboxing as if it were untrusted.

Don't modify catalogs directly.

> If not, what are the specific languages that can be set up to be trusted or are trusted.

Just these,

- PL/PgSQL runs as trusted.
- PL/Perl can run as trusted or untrusted.
- PL/TCL can run as trusted or untrusted.

That's it for the built-in PLs. Notably, PL/Python cannot run as trusted [due to *fundamental* design limitations with the CPython interpreter that make creation of a restricted execution environment impossible](https://docs.python.org/2/library/restricted.html). It's possible to create a "trusted-ish" Python runtime where an attacker is protected from simple mistakes but can break out of the sandbox with effort, but PL/Python does not support this, nor is any patch to enable it likely to be accepted.

There are also a bunch of out-of-tree procedural languages, some of which support trusted mode. Notably, PL/V8 (JavaScript), PL/Lua and PL/Java support trusted mode. There are probably others.

(On a side note, I really would love to see adoption of in-core a trusted-enabled PL/Javascript as a default in-core PL, or even better, PL/C# for .NET via Mono or .NET Core).

Comment: There is a [matrix of these here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PL_Matrix). And I def +1 making pl/v8 in-core pl.

Comment: Yes,  PL/C# for .NET via Mono or .NET Core - would be great!

Answer (score 4):

For those who are interested in an "official source", there is the [PL Matrix](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PL_Matrix) in PostgreSQL wiki, which contains a "(un)trusted" column telling whether a language is trusted or not.